# 2 dimensional array in C language

Tags: c, arrays

I am passing a 2d array to a function to print the output, but the output I am getting is erroneous

---

function

```
void PrintArray(unsigned char mat[][4]){
    int i, j;
    printf("\n");
    for(i = 0;i<4;i++){
        for(j = 0;j<4;j++)
                printf("%3x",mat[i][j]);

        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

---

main function

```
int main(){

int i,j;
//static int c=175;
unsigned char  state[4][4], key[4][4], expandedKey[176];


printf("enter the value to be decrypted");
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    for(j=0;j<4;j++)
        scanf("%x",(unsigned int *)&state[j][i]);
PrintArray(state);

return 0;
}
```

---

expected output

```
  1  5  9  c   
  2  6  0  d 
  3  7  a  e
  4  8  b  f
```

actual output

```
h2o@h2o-Vostro-1015:~$ ./a.out enter the value to be decrypted 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 a b c d e f

  1  5  9  c   
  0  0  0  d 
  0  0  0  e
  0  0  0  f
```

I checked the method of passing 2d array, its correct I think, but not sure why m getting this output, kindly advise...

Comment: what output do you expect?

Comment: @Beed edited the ques, simply entering the array by user and displaying it on console..

Comment: What do you think happens when `scanf` treats the pointer into a `char` array as a pointer to `unsigned int`? The typecast may silence the warnings, but that doesn't mean the code works as expected.

Comment: @WhozCraig it doesn't matter.. does it? if u look at the code it doesnt matter at all, furthermore the expected output is  according to [j][i] index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The array passing is correct. However, the scanf function seems to overwrite some values to be 0 due to the variable type %x.

The data type specified by %x is "int" because %x is like %d (except that the input is hexadecimal). The data occupies 4 bytes (typically). So when the user enters a number, say, 1, four bytes 01 00 00 00 (assuming little-endianness on an Intel machine) will be written to memory instead of 1. The trailing 0s will erase some existing elements that are stored in the byte array, because in the byte array, each element is allocated only 1 byte.

Try the following code:

```
int main() {
int i,j;
//static int c=175;
unsigned char  state[4][4], key[4][4], expandedKey[176];

printf("enter the value to be decrypted");
int tmp;
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    for(j=0;j<4;j++) {
        scanf("%x", &tmp);
        state[j][i] = (char)tmp;
    }
PrintArray(state);
```

Comment: it worked like a charm :) , can u please explain the reason behind this overwriting due to %x, thanks a lot...

Comment: Sure. The data type specified by %x is "int" because %x is like %d (except that the input is hexadecimal). The data occupies 4 bytes (typically). So when the user enters a number, say, 1, four bytes 01 00 00 00 (assuming little-endianness on an Intel machine) will be written to memory instead of 1. The trailing 0s will erase some existing elements that are stored in the byte array, because in the byte array, each element is allocated only 1 byte. Hope I explained it more clearly now. :)

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to go out on a limb and say that your problem lies here:

```
scanf("%x",(unsigned int *)&state[j][i]);
```

`state[i][j]` is sized to hold a single `char`, but you're telling `scanf` to treat it as a pointer to `unsigned int`; this likely means that `scanf` is overwriting adjacent array elements, since `sizeof (unsigned int)` is most likely greater than `sizeof (char)`.

Change the declaration of the array from `char` to `unsigned int` in both `main` and `PrintArray`, and lose the cast in `scanf`.

Comment: Yep, that's it. As alternative suggestion, if the OP doesn't want to change the type of `state`, the reading code could use `scanf` to a local `unsigned int` and then assign its value to `state[j][i]`.